# What's the right way to call Introspect endpoint in Microsoft IdentityServer 4

Tags: identityserver4

I'm able using postman to get an access token from Microsoft Identity Server 4.

[image]

This the response:

[image]

Now i would like to authenticate the token using the introspection endpoint, but the return is 401 unhautorized, maybe is missing some data into the request to introspect endpoint?

[image]

Comment: this helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126909/how-to-correctly-use-the-introspection-endpoint-with-identity-server-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the token introspection enpoint in Postman, I use:

- POST to https://localhost:6001/connect/introspect
- Add the Authorization header, with the value "Basic cGF5bWVudDpteWFwaXNlY3JldA==". Where the secret is the apiname/secret. In my case it is payment and myapisecret as password.
- Add a body x-www-form-urlencoded, with a key named token and the value is my access token.

That should be all.

[image]

Comment: yes, using https://demo.identityserver.io/ i can validate the token, but using the same procedure on my local identity server i get 401 unhautorized. this the IS log: [17:29:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.HashedSharedSecretValidator
No shared secret configured for client.
[17:29:09 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.SecretValidator
Secret validators could not validate secret
[17:29:09 Error] IdentityServer4.Validation.ApiSecretValidator
API validation failed.
[17:29:09 Error] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint
API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.

Comment: have you set the ApiSecrets in your ApiResource? you use the APIResource name and secret to create the basic authentication against the token introspection endpoint.

Comment: yes I solved it, but there not documentation about it, i had to add a record into the table ApiSecrets (i started from the m$ sample where configuration is stored into sql server database). to format cirrectly the secret need to write some line of code using the class Secret of IdentityServer assembly. also i wuold like to know if that string can be decrypted. K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=

Comment: The secret is hashed in IdentityServer, so it should be very hard to brute-force. But the authorize header string is of course not secure, but that's not so important.