# Generating Reference Token Instead of JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4, identityserver3, dotnetopenauth

Please find below the steps I applied in order to generate Reference Token instead of JWT:

1. In the [Clients] table, I updated property [AccessTokenType] = 1. Please note that this is the client configured to be used from Angular Frontend app.
   [image: Clients Table]

[image: ClientScopes Table]

*OIDC client configuration (Angular App)*

```
"IdentityGuardsConfig": {
"oidcSettings": {
  "authority": "http://localhost:5000",
  "client_id": "local_spa",
  "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/#/identity-guards/auth-callback#",
  "post_logout_redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200",
  "response_type": "id_token token",
  "scope": "openid profile inspection_profile",
  "filterProtocolClaims": true,
  "loadUserInfo": true,
  "automaticSilentRenew": true,
  "silent_redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/#/identity-guards/silent-refresh#"
},
```

2- Since API (/connect/introspect) is secure, I had to create API Resource and API Secret (as per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126909/how-to-correctly-use-the-introspection-endpoint-with-identity-server-4)). Also as per the thread, I had to assign the exact scopes requested from Frontend client (3 scopes ==> opened, profile, inspection_profile)

[image: ApiResources Table]
[image: ApiSecrets Table]
[image: ApiScopes Table]

After applying the above configuration, IdentityServer service is returning reference token, also the reference token is being persisted in [PersistedGrants] table
[image: PersistedGrants Table]

To validate the reference token, I was able to do that by hitting (/connect/introspect) API from Postman (below is the converted cURL request)

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic bG9jYWxfc3BhOlBAc3N3MHJk' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=f007eff8fc2a3d8d9af7cb605b93b78d7004880d24356acebf928dae5a48dd8e'
```

Below is the response I recived for the above cURL request:

```
{
"iss": "http://localhost:5000",
"nbf": 1640694748,
"exp": 1640698348,
"aud": "http://localhost:5000/resources",
"client_id": "local_spa",
"sub": "f6a5ccec-9d70-4c7c-ab50-7a932f685cac",
"auth_time": 1640694748,
"idp": "local",
"amr": "pwd",
"email": "admin@isp.com",
"name": "admin@isp.com",
"given_name": "admin",
"phone_number": "0506198339",
"role": "SystemAdmin",
"preferred_username": "admin@isp.com",
"active": true,
"scope": "openid profile inspection_profile"
}
```

**However, when I tried to access (/.well-known/openid-configuration) I’m getting the below exception:**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> Exception: Found identity scopes and API scopes that use the same names. This is an invalid configuration. Use different names for identity scopes and API scopes. Scopes found: openid, profile, inspection_profile
> IdentityServer4.Stores.IResourceStoreExtensions.Validate(IEnumerable identity, IEnumerable apiResources) in IResourceStoreExtensions.cs, line 60

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message explains pretty well what the problem is.

*Found identity scopes and API scopes that use the same names. This is an invalid configuration. Use different names for identity scopes and API scopes.*

You need to make sure the **IdentityResource** and **ApiScope** names are not the same.

Comment: Then if I removed [openid profile inspection_profile] scopes from ApiScope, the (/connect/introspect) endpoint will not work because initially when the reference token generated, it requested the previous 3 scopes.

So I'm missing something here?

Comment: see my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811157/apiresource-vs-apiscope-vs-identityresource/63812939#63812939

APIScope should not contain "openid profile or introspection_profile", they are only meant to be used in IdentityResources.

Answer (score 0):

@Tore Nestenius
You were correct. As adivsed I moved [inspection_profile] scope from [IdentityResources] to [ApiResources].
Also for all custom claim that I already have in [IdentityClaims], I re-linked them to the [openid] profile.